# How to find optimal number of epoch in general while using h2o.deeplearning()?

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network

As i have just started studying about Neural networks modelling , I wanted to know that,  Suppose i have a dataset for classification problem and i am using

```
churn_model <- h2o.deeplearning(x = setdiff(names(churn), names(churn)[10]),
                             y = names(churn)[10],
                             training_frame = churnTrain,
                             validation_frame = churnValidation,
                             distribution = "multinomial",
                             activation = "RectifierWithDropout",
                             hidden = c(200,200,200),
                             hidden_dropout_ratio = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1),
                             epochs = 50 , stopping_rounds = 0,
                             l1 = 1e-5)
```

So how can i determine through any function or something what will be the number of epoch that i can use?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you estimate it empirically. Start training with an initially large number of iterations/epochs and stop it whenever you observe overfitting, i.e. you validation error goes up while train error diminishes. This is called early stopping.

If you do not observe overfitting, increase the number of iterations, until validation error becomes stable.